# Facebook API: Authorizing yourself (without logging in)

Tags: facebook

I simply wish to access my own personal profile, and get access to all my notes. In order to do this, I DON'T want to have to login each time via the Facebook frontend, as I know the password.

```
$user = $facebook->require_login();
```

Not what I want. I want to login straight away, without the need of typing in anything. For example:

```
$user = $facebook->log_me_in_please(username, password);
```

This code is obviously non-existant. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Should i be using "Facebook Connect"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't worked with Facebook's APIs, but I did a little digging around to try to find a solution, and I think you might need to approach this in a different manner.

1) [authorize your website](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Authorizing_Applications) as an Application.
2) Authorize your Application (website) to access Facebook on your behalf, and save the token somewhere (database? file?)
3) Use your site to make various requests to Facebook on your behalf.

The downside is that this is a lot of code just to update stuff for yourself.
The upside is that once you implement this, you can re-use it again & again.

hoep that helps.

Comment: Your are kind of right. But in the end, I had to do this: http://www.emcro.com/blog/2009/01/facebook-infinite-session-keys-no-more/ --> for infinite session key. And then use: $facebook->set_user($facebook_userid, $infinite_session_key);

Comment: I kept investigating, and just came back to tell you about "infinite session key", but I guess you already found it. Good stuff :)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this facebook neither policy nor Api allow to do so. Secondly proxy login to facebook violates its privacy policy